# Gmail inbox displays Persian letter as two question marks

Tags: .net, string, email, encoding, gmail

I'm sending emails, whose subject and body are stored and then retrieved from SQL Server, using `SmtpClient` in C#.

And for `MailMessage` I have `SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8`.

This is what is displayed in Gmail inbox:

[image: What is displayed]

`دسترسی محدود به تقو��م گوگل`

When it should be displayed like so:

[image: What should be displayed]

`دسترسی محدود به تقویم گوگل`

What could be causing this?

Comment: Are you sure you stored it in SQL Server correctly? You need `nvarchar`

Comment: @Charlieface Yes, ```nvarchar``` is used. What's odd is that only this single character is not displayed correctly.

Comment: Please [*do not* use (sole) images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3439404) in your [mcve].
Copy the actual text, paste it into the question, then format it as code.  Post a hexadecimal dump in case of (partially) binary content.  A question mark in a black diamond is (supposedly) [Glyph 0: the `.notdef` glyph](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/recom#glyph-0-the-notdef-glyph).

Comment: @JosefZ The actual email subject added.